# Обновить div при клике на кнопку

Tags: javascript

Подскажите как можно обновить конкретный 'div' при клике на кнопку.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function searchClicked()
        {       
var urequest = document.getElementById("searchform").value
var scriptid = document.getElementById('myclass2')
scriptid.src = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/videos?vq=' + urequest + '&max-results=8&alt=json-in-script&callback=showMyVideos&orderby=relevance&sortorder=descending&format=5&fmt=18'
        }
</script>

                        <div id="searchblock" class="searchblock">
                            <div class="formqwerty">
                                <input id="searchform" class="inputbox" type="text" maxlength="40" size="40" onfocus="if (this.value=='Search for something here') this.value='';" name="q">
                                <input onclick="searchClicked()" id="search-submit-button" class="button" type="submit" value="" onfocus="this.blur();" name="s">
                            </div>
                            <div id="scriptdiv">
                            <script id="myclass2" src="http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/videos?vq=&max-results=8&alt=json-in-script&callback=showMyVideos&orderby=relevance&sortorder=descending&format=5&fmt=18"></script>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Нужно обновить div с id="scriptdiv", который содержит скрипт с id="myclass2". Сейчас при вводе в строку поиска текста и клике на кнопку просто обновляется параметр "src" у script id="myclass2". Но не идет запрос по обновленному скрипту. Как можно обновить содержимое блока div id="scriptdiv"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Чуть-чуть изменил поведение функции, теперь не нужно обращаться к myclass2

```
function searchClicked() {
    var urequest = document.getElementById("searchform").value;
    var scriptDiv = document.getElementById('scriptdiv');
    var script= document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/videos?vq=' + urequest + '&max-results=8&alt=json-in-script&callback=showMyVideos&orderby=relevance&sortorder=descending&format=5&fmt=18';
    scriptDiv.innerHTML = '';
    scriptDiv.appendChild(script);
}
```

Ну и на [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zhukovroman/SeVBc/) сами можете проверить.

Comment: Спасибо Роман!

Comment: Не за что, удачи! Но вообще смотрите в сторону AJAX на будущее.